# Error cloning git repository, returns error code 501

Tags: git, apache, ssl

I'm trying to create a git "server" with Apache using HTTPS protocol. For that I've created created an alias pointing the directory "git". Then in this directory I have multiple folders, one for each user, protected by `htaccess` & `htpasswd` for authentication, and finally one folder per repositories of each user. So I'm supposed to access to my repos with links of that form:

> https: //localhost/git/user/repo.git

I then followed this tutorial : http://www.it-connect.fr/mettre-en-place-une-connexion-ssl-avec-wamp%EF%BB%BF/  to enable HTTPS.

But when I try to clone one of my repos, by doing:

> git clone https: //user:pass@localhost/git/user/repo.git

it returns the message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https:
>   //user:pass@localhost/git/user/repo.git': The requested URL returned
>   error : 501

.

I watched to the ssl access & error logs to understand why and it seems that somewhere it request are modifies because instead of a typical GET request I have :

> [Sat Jul 19 13:05:36.794602 2014] [core:error] [pid 8572:tid 1580]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:59226] AH00135: Invalid method in request ]\xdaGET
>   /git/user/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1

And I agree with the server that `]\xdaGET` is an invalid method, be cause it should be `GET`.

Does someone know where that problem comes from ?

Answer (score 1):

That means you git client is too old. Please upgrade it to the latest version, and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you have a space after the `https:` in your URL? It might just be a syntax error based on that. Should be `https://`, not `https: //`